# How to get ABI from vyper source code?

Tags: abi, vyper

My main gold is to [interact with contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002495/how-to-call-an-existing-contract-from-web3-python).

Rexmix online IDE gives solidity and Yul language. To interact my contract I need ABI

**Question**
How does vyper source code give me an ABI file?

Answer (score 1):

Found it `-f abi`
`vyper -f abi yourFileName.vy`

https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying-contracts.html?highlight=abi#deploying-a-contract